# proneness to + [verb] instead of proneness to + [noun]

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

This is my first question in here so I ask you to be tolerant with any faux pas I may commit.
Having said so, my question is about the word proneness, of which I've only found examples in which it is followed by a noun.

Can it be followed by a verb? If so, gerund or infinitive (e.g. *my proneness to observe/observing*)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for using _faux pas_ – I just learnt a useful term. (Of course, I had to refer to a dictionary to understand its pronunciation, meaning and usage.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can explain this well but I think *tendency to observe* or *inclination to observe* would sound more natural than *proneness to observe*, and it is perhaps for this reason that we don't much see *proneness* being followed by a verb.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary has citations that show *proneness to* followed by both nouns and infinitives, but none showing it followed by the *-ing* form of a verb. That is not to say that such a construction is impossible. Much, as always, depends on the context.